# How to use type adDecimal when passing parameters from Excel VBA to sql database?

Tags: mysql, excel, vba, mariadb

I'm using Excel/VBA to communicate with my sql database, using an ADODB connection and parameters. In my database, I have a column of type Decimal(13,4), and therefore tried to use the VBA type adDecimal to create the parameter:

```
Set param = dbCmd.CreateParameter("myvalue", adDecimal, adParamInput, 0, myvalue)
param.NumericScale = 4
param.Precision = 13
```

However, this fails as soon as myvalue cannot be stored as a long anymore, meaning as soon as 1000*myvalue > 2147483647. No error occurs, but the value written to the database is gibberish/overflowing.

I have tried converting myvalue to a double `CDbl(myvalue)` or decimal `CDec(myvalue)` when passing it into the CreateParameter function, but that had no effect.

What solves the problem is to create a parameter of type adDouble instead. So, while I have found a solution that will work for me, I'm still puzzled about the problem. Is there some internal conversion happening, or do I misunderstand how to use type adDecimal? What is the correct way to handle decimal database values in VBA?

Here is a minimal working example (given an existing mysql/mariaDB database):
In the database:

```
CREATE TABLE mytable ( 
  id SMALLINT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, 
  dec1 DECIMAL(13,4),
  dec2 DECIMAL(13,4)
);
```

In VBA:

```
Public Sub test()
    WriteToDB 123456789.1234, 123456789.1234
    WriteToDB 214748.3647, 214748.3647
    WriteToDB 214748.3648, 214748.3648
End Sub

Public Sub WriteToDB(dec1 As Variant, dec2 As Variant)
    Dim dbConn As ADODB.Connection
    Dim dbCmd As ADODB.Command
    Dim sql As String
    Dim param As ADODB.Parameter
    
    'Open database connection
    Set dbConn = New ADODB.Connection
    dbConn.Open "Provider=MSDASQL;DSN=XXX;DATABASE=XXX;UID=XXX;PWD=XXX;"
    
    Set dbCmd = New ADODB.Command
    dbCmd.ActiveConnection = dbConn
    dbCmd.CommandType = adCmdText
    
    'Define command and parameters
    sql = "INSERT INTO mytable (dec1, dec2) VALUES (?, ?)"
    Set param = dbCmd.CreateParameter("dec1", adDecimal, adParamInput, 0, dec1)
    param.NumericScale = 4
    param.Precision = 13
    dbCmd.Parameters.Append param
    
    Set param = dbCmd.CreateParameter("dec2", adDouble, adParamInput, 0, dec2)
    dbCmd.Parameters.Append param
  
    'Execute command
    dbCmd.CommandText = sql
    dbCmd.Execute , , adExecuteNoRecords
    
    'Close connection
    dbConn.Close
End Sub
```

Outcome in database:

```
MariaDB [XXX]> SELECT * FROM mytable;
+----+--------------+----------------+
| id | dec1         | dec2           |
+----+--------------+----------------+
|  1 |  191227.7282 | 123456789.1234 |
|  2 |  214748.3647 |    214748.3647 |
|  3 | -214748.3640 |    214748.3648 |
+----+--------------+----------------+
```

As you can see, the dec1 values for id=1 and id=3 are incorrect.

Comment: Did you try something like `WriteToDB CDec(123456789.1234), 123456789.1234` in order to pass an actual decimal-subtyped variant ?

Comment: @TimWilliams : Yes, I tried that. Still the same problem unfortunately.

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem with  10.1.48-MariaDB, Excel 14.0 (32-bit) and mysql-connector-odbc-8.0.23-win32 which I just installed. What versions do you have ?

Comment: @CDP1802, that's interesting! I have 10.3.27-MariaDB, Microsoft 365 Excel Version 2102, 64-bit with VBA 7.1, mariadb-connector-odbc-3.1.9-win64, and using ActiveX Data Objects 6.1 Library (switching to library version 2.8 doesn't solve the issue). So, hm, it's a setup issue?

Comment: I installed the mariadb-connector but for some reason the ODBC manager will not  create a DSN so I am afraid I can't help much more. You could see if the mysql-connector is any different.

Comment: @CDP1802 I finally found time to install the mysql driver (MySQL ODBC Driver 8.0 Ani/Unicode Driver). And the problem is gone. So it is indeed a problem with the odbc connector!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out this is indeed a bug. In case anyone runs into the same problem, here's what you can do:

- Update to a newer mariadb-connector version. According to the [bug report](https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/ODBC-305), the issue is fixed in version 3.1.12
- Use the mysql-connecter instead of the mariadb-connector
- As described in the question, create the parameter as adDouble in excel